# Absolute Layout inside Stack Layout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a floating button in the bottom right corner of my page inside the StackLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:fab="clr-namespace:FAB.Forms;assembly=FAB.Forms"
    x:Class="Hura.Pages.LatestNews"
    Title="Latest news">
    <StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="5">
        <Label Text="Latest news" FontSize="Medium"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lsvNews"/>

        <Label Text="Latest activities" FontSize="Medium"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lsvActivities"/>

        <Label Text="Good Mording" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="xyz"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            VerticalOptions="End">
            <Button Text="gggggg"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

but the button appears bellow the label. But I want it to appear above the label and not below it.

[image]

How can I position the button in the bottom-left corner above the label?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your issue here is that the `StackLayout` is simply going to position items in the order that you add them. So since you added the `AbsoluteLayout` after adding your `Label`, your `Button` is going to show up lower than your `Label`.

Obviously you could move the `Label` beneath your `AbsoluteLayout` and get the effect you are asking for like so:

```
...


<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="xyz"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                VerticalOptions="End">
  <Button Text="gggggg"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
<Label Text="Good Mording" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

...
```

But the whole point of a floating button is for it to actually **float** above other content. In the example that you show, your `Button` would never float above anything. In order to get the `Button` to float over other items you would need to add the entire `StackLayout` to your `AbsoluteLayout`. Something like this (note that I have not tested this code so you may need to play with it a bit):

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <StackLayout Spacing="10"
               Padding="5"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
      ...
  </StackLayout>

  <Button Text="gggggg"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"   
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,AutoSize,AutoSize"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The important bits above are that everything is within the `AbsoluteLayout`, which means you are able to stack your controls correctly. The other important items are the `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds`. The `LayoutFlags` and `LayoutBounds` on the `StackLayout` basically just tell the `StackLayout` that it can take up the entire screen. The `LayoutFlags` and `LayoutBounds` on the `Button` say that the `Button` needs to be in the bottom right corner and that it can size itself.

Comment: Would like to point out that the `LayoutFlags` and `LayoutBounds` properties are very important to make sure everything inside the `StackLayout` shows up as expected. Thanks for this answer to point me in the right direction!

Comment: Top right - `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,AutoSize,AutoSize"`  and bottom left  `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,AutoSize,AutoSize"` for buttons

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer especially the point that StackLayout should be inside AbsoluteLayout! Precious!

Answer (score 2):

Make it reverse put Stack Layout inside Absolute Layout to work like expected

**Here is sample code**

```
Button btnPlus = new Button()
{
    Text = "FAB"
    HeightRequest = 50,
    WidthRequest = 50
};

StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Children = { STACK_CHILDRENS }
};

AbsoluteLayout absoluteLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(btnPlus, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(btnPlus, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.95, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(stackLayout, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(stackLayout, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));

absoluteLayout.Children.Add(btnPlus);
absoluteLayout.Children.Add(stackLayout);

Content = absoluteLayout;
```